# Specializing functions with generic return types

Tags: c++, templates, specialization, template-function

I have what I think is a simple question regarding specializing functions with generic return types. I haven't been able to find another post that answers my question, but perhaps that post exists and I'm just not understanding it (or I haven't found it). So, hopefully this isn't a repetition, but here it goes:
The following code illustrates my problem:
A.h

```
    class A {
        //...
        template<typename T> T func() { 
            cout << "Generic" << endl;
            T temp;
            return temp;
        }
    }
```

A.cpp

```
        //...
        template<> inline double A::func<double>() { 
            cout << "Double" << endl; 
            double d;
            return d;
        }
```

Usage:

```
int main() {
    A a;
    int var1 = a.func<int>();
    double var2 = a.func<double>();
}
```

What you can probably gather from the code is that I want to specialize the generic *func()* function in the case when *double* is the template parameter. However, when run I see:

> Generic
>
> Generic

Instead of:

> Generic
>
> Double

Why is the generic version being called both times? How can I get the behavior I want?

I'll quickly describe the real life situation, too, in case the answer to my question is "you'll probably never want to do this." I simply want to write a class that parses command line arguments (strings) into various data types (int, double, bool, etc.). One obvious approach is to write a separate function for each desired type. Another approach could be to pass a variable by reference, instead of returning a value, and overload the function for each type.

However, I was thinking that a specialized function would make for more extensible code. My goal was to cause an error to occur for the generic case, with some error message saying something like "I haven't implemented a parser for your target type yet," while each specialized case will implement the appropriate string-to-*type* parser. I figured that this would allow me to add parsers for new types down the line without ever having to modify original class files, which is relevant to me since I am building this argument parser into a library.

Ok, hopefully that makes sense. I'm more interested in an explanation of why the code doesn't do what I expect than a solution, but either is appreciated!

Comment: in which file did you put `main()`?

Answer (score 3):

The specialization of the function is "hidden" inside the .cpp file, so the compiler never sees it when compiling `main` (which presumably only includes `A.h`).

To fix this, declare the specialization in `A.h`:

```
class A {
   // ...
};

template<> double A::func<double>();
```

If you keep the `inline`, you can probably also move the whole definition of the function into the header.

Comment: When I took his code it didn't even compile, when I got it to it behaved as expected

Comment: Does that mean if I want to add another specialized version of the function, then I have to edit the original header file? In other words, is there any way to accomplish the scenario I described in the question?

Comment: @aaronman It's incomplete code. Adding #includes should be all that's left. Can you tell me what compiler you are using? I'm using GCC 4.5.3 through Cygwin.

Comment: @womple No, there isn't. With templates the compiler needs to be able to see the entire definition at the callsite.

Comment: clang++ 3.2 I think, I also couldn't call the function in main because it was private